# Struct union packing, unpacking and storing

Tags: c++, struct, c++17, unions

I recently started to play with C++'s advanced data types, pretty new to this data type. And I have not mastered bit shifting either, so please take this question with grain of salt.

I want to use unions in my new project to store variables in a single MySQL field.
e.g. rather than having multiple fields for each parts I want to use one field with preferably varchar field (depending on the bit size length) and store this variable in only one field.

First of all, I am compiling my project as x86, so endianness is not an issue based on my researches about unions.

Let's say I have this current data structure;

```
// Current Data Structure
enum
{
    PLAYER_PART1,
    PLAYER_PART2,
    PLAYER_PART3,
    PLAYER_PART4,
    PLAYER_PART5,
    PLAYER_PART_MAX_NUM,
};

struct SPlayerData
{
    //...
    uint16_t part[PLAYER_PART_MAX_NUM];
} TPlayerData;

void StoreData()
{
    //... Update MySQL table with m_PlayerData.part[N];
    //.. Do this seperately for each MySQL field e.g. "PLAYER_PART2" = m_PlayerData.part[PLAYER_PART2]
    //.. So in total we have five player part fields in MySQL table.
}

void UpdateData()
{
    // To update the parts
    // I get the index of the part and set it.
    // m_PlayerData.part[PLAYER_PART2] = N;
}
```

And... this is my new version for storing parts;

```
typedef union
{
    struct s_piece
    {
        uint16_t part1; // PLAYER_PART1
        uint16_t part2; // PLAYER_PART2
    } piece;

    uint32_t package; // 32 Bits
} TPartWear;

struct SPlayerData
{
    //...
    TPartWear part;
} TPlayerData;

void StoreData()
{
    // Now we have only one 32 bit integer
    // Set update: m_PlayerData.part.package; AWESOME!
    // And we dont need these multiple repetitive PLAYER_PARTX fields anymore.
}

void UpdateData()
{
    // To update the parts
    // I just set m_PlayerData.part.piece.part1 = N;
    // Now it is simpler and more readable.
}
```

Now that's a beauty, I can store parts in only one MySQL field and save some more space and have more readability overall. Very nice.

**THE QUESTION**

As you can see on the new version I am having 2x16 bits of unsigned shorts, and package value type is 32 bits. Now I can go up to 64 bits if I use 4x unsigned shorts (4x16). That's cool.

The problem is... How am I supposed to have let's say 5x unsigned shorts which is 5x16=80 bits. How am I supposed to handle this > 64 bits numbers in an union struct? Am I going to have a char array or some sort? And what would be more efficient and safest way to do this?

Also, I want to access to package variable as easy as possible, I do not want to manually shift the bytes...

Thank you!

Comment: FWIW, this code is illegal in C++.  C++ doesn't support type punning through a union like C does except for very a specific case where the objects in the union are standard layout classes and they share the same initial common sequence of members.

Comment: You're right, after researching a little bit more about unions, apparently, union type punning invokes undefined behaviour in C++. But not in C. Now, what would be the best way to store these "player parts" in one packed integer or char array etc? Any ideas then? Cheers

Comment: `std::memcpy` is one way to pack and unpack data.

Comment: All objects can be viewed as an array of bytes (note that the reverse is not true, so getting the `uint16_t`s back out requires some compromises), so it will be legal to cast to a `char*`. Watch out for endian disagreements, though.

Comment: "_I want to use unions in my new project to store variables in a single MySQL field. e.g. rather than having multiple fields for each part_" - No - no - no !!! [What is Normalization?](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html)

Comment: @TedLyngmo thank you for you advice, I graduated from computer science and we also had database normalization lessons too.. I want to do this because I am currently doing normalization :). Now imagine for each player I have 50 different skill types and each player has different skill level values, cooldown timings and etc. Would it be better to store 50 different skill values specific for a player and have millions of records for few thousands of players OR, have one field in MySQL which has a BLOB or TEXT and store these skill values... Which one you would go for normalizaton?...

Comment: @liveth19937 The set of skills should, in a traditional, database be in a table of its own, not packed into a field together with the character. `character->char_skills->skills`. The middle table holds the `character(key)-1-many->skills(key)` mapping. You make a view over that to get what you're after. You're optimizing on the wrong level if you think you'll outperform modern DBMS's with hacks like this. Let it do its job and think about optimizing/reorganizing later. If you go the route you're about to take, you'll most likely have a hard time restructuring it later if you need to.

Comment: Alternatively, look at MongoDB. It may be closer to what you want.

Comment: If you find a bunch of other programmers shuddering at what you're doing, or if you're trying to get around how the tool you're using works -- either you're using the wrong tool, or you're taking a wrong approach. I would use a separate table that is basically key-value pairs, with either integer, boolean, or string value types.

Comment: @JosephLarson thank you for the advice, you are definitely right! I posted a solution for my problem check it please.

Comment: @JosephLarson as an addition I would like to thank you for that amazing advice...! I think this has to be quote of the month: **"If you find a bunch of other programmers shuddering at what you're doing, or if you're trying to get around how the tool you're using works -- either you're using the wrong tool, or you're taking a wrong approach."**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after a little bit more research I decided to go with storing as BLOB approach.

Here is a working example of what I did:

```
// Data Structure
enum EPlayerParts
{
    PLAYER_PART_HEAD,
    PLAYER_PART_ARMOR,
    PLAYER_PART_WEAPON,
    // ...
    PLAYER_PART_MAX_NUM,
};

typedef struct SPlayerData
{
    //...
    uint16_t parts[PLAYER_PART_MAX_NUM]; // or WORD or unsigned short
};

// Functions
void CreatePlayerPrototype(/*args...*/)
{
    // Prepping for binary conversion
    static char s_binary[256 + 1];
    static char s_queryStr[256 + 1];

    // Escape
    mysql_real_escape_string(SQLHandle, s_binary, m_playerData->parts, sizeof(m_playerData->parts));

    // Binary conversion
    _snprintf(s_queryStr, sizeof(s_queryStr), "... '%s' ...", /*...*/ s_binary /*...*/);

    // Insert ...
}

void SetPlayerPrototype(SQLMsg* msg)
{
    // ... SQL res get message and loop
    size_t int column = 0;
    
    // Copy over BLOB data
    memcpy(m_playerData.parts, row[column++], sizeof(m_playerData.parts));
}

void SetPlayerPart(uint8_t partPos, uint16_t partVal)
{
    assert(partPos < PLAYER_PART_MAX_NUM);
    m_playerData.parts[partPos] = partVal;
}

uint16_t GetPlayerPart(uint8_t partPos)
{
    assert(partPos < PLAYER_PART_MAX_NUM);
    return m_playerData.parts[partPos];
}
```

I store values as BLOB in MySQL table in only one row, after I fetch the target BLOB value, I execute memcpy to target structure. And rest of it is just type punning into the structure.

When I am going to store the structure with snprintf I transform structure into a BLOB array and insert / update in the database table field.

So far, everything's working fine and passed all of my testings. If you have anymore recommendation regarding to make it better or faster or any concerns, please do comment.

Edit: Depending on the size of my structure I went for **tinyblob** type in MySQL field. It's capacity is 255 bytes.

Comment: This is something better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) but as an early warning: This would not pass any code review process I've ever been involved in in the past 30 years. To me it seems you disregarded the advice telling you about the illegality of type punning in C++, threw your degree in database modelling and the normal forms out the window and just went with the "quick fix". There's a difference between "trying things out" and "research". The code that seems to be working right now is extremely fragile. Real research would make that obvious to you.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you for the notice but I did not do any type punning in the latest working copy... see the memcpy function in SetPlayerPrototype please (I applied type punning only in Set and Get parts, and I think this is C++ aliasing rule compliant, isn't it?), also if you have more recommendations, I am more than welcome to receive, Cheers

Comment: Ok, I thought you stuck with type punning. It's hard to see exactly what it does though. Where's the type punning in the set and Get parts? Btw, you know that you don't need to `typedef struct`s or `typedef union`s, right? `struct Name { ... };` or `union Name { ... };` typedefines `Name` automatically in C++.